# Application crashing and show error "malloc: can't allocate region"

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am creating an application with lots of images. By Api I am getting those images and then after I am showing those images in collection view.

For few minutes application is working fine but after that it crashed and showing error

```
"malloc: can't allocate region"
:*** mach_vm_map(size=3145728, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to ran out of memory

Check the memory usage of the app.

[image]

Comment: Hi @seunghwan lee Thanks for your reply, I checked the memory its size was around 30MB and I am using iPad, My application saving images in cache and I think its crashing due to full of cache memory